# Creating a folder with a specific set of subfolders

Tags: content-type, folder

just wondering if you can help I'm only just starting with SharePoint Development

I have a request for some c# code that will allow users to do the following:

Within a specific Site Collection e.g. HR then document library named Personnel click on a New Content Type Button that does the following.
1. Prompts for a new folder name (bloggs, joe) 
2. Creates a specific set of sub folders

Seems simple enough but all of the articles/blogs I've come across are incomplete or are so poorly structured it's like trying to decipher hieroglyphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Ribbon button, call a layouts page as a Pop up page and pass it the ListID. The layouts page will contain a textbox where you can input folder and subfolder names separated by a separator like comma. It will also have a button and clicking on button will create folders in the list. The example [here](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/07/invoke-server-side-code-on-sharepoint_9855.html) shows how to Invoke server side code on SharePoint ribbon click using SharePoint Page dialog